# Django rest-framework; show different content to authetificated and anonymous users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to implement rest_framework for Django 2.
I have a URL that should show diffrent content for authentificated users.
Anonymous users just will get a limited view, authentificated will see everything. 
In the documentation I can only methods that will deny everything, but not a if else clause.
Basicly I try something like this:

```
class StoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
if IsAuthenticated == True:
    queryset = Story.objects.all()
else:
    queryset = Story.objects.filter(story_is_save=True)       
serializer_class = StorySerializer
```

Obviously IsAuthenticated is not a True/False statement i can query. 
Any ideas how I could do this easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `get_queryset` method:

```
class StoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            queryset = Story.objects.all()
        else:
            queryset = Story.objects.filter(story_is_save=True)       
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks, also I had to rework some stuff (initaly i had everythin in the urls.py, now i have all cleany seperated and solved it in my views.py: `def rest_story_list(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated == True:
        stories = Story.objects.all()
    else:
        stories = Story.objects.filter(story_is_save=True) 
    serializer = StorySerializer(stories, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

`